# Excel VBA/ Userform, how can I tell userform the row I'm searching and input the data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Thanks to Christofer Weber, I just improved my code and changed my problem here:

The code is for searching for the fermenter number for the first step, and when the number is found the system will ask users to input data in the userform and put this information in the specific rows corresponding to the fermenter number found.

Now the problem is I'm not sure how to link these two steps. The number can be successfully found and the user will be asked to input information after that, I set a public variable which can be used in the two subs. But somehow the data seems still not be able to entered in the spreadsheet.

Here is my code:

Public m as Long
        Sub CmdSearch3_Click()

```
Dim FerNum As String, totRows As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
totRows = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
FerNum = CStr(InputBox("Please enter the fermenter number you are looking for."))

If FerNum = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the fermenter number you wish to search."

Else

    For m = 2 To totRows

        If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(m, 3)) <> Trim(FerNum) And m = totRows Then
            MsgBox ("Sorry, the fermenter number " & FerNum & " is not found.")

        ElseIf Trim(Sheet1.Cells(m, 3)) = Trim(FerNum) Then
            MsgBox ("Please enter the data need here.")
            DTPickerActualHarvestDate.SetFocus
            Exit For
        End If
    Next m

End If

End Sub
```

Here is the second part for inputting the data.

```
Sub cmdAddRecord_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet, AddNew As Range
Set wks = sheet1
If m>0 Then
m=m-1
End if
Set AddNew = wks.Range("A1")
AddNew.Offset(m, 6).Value = DTPickerActualHarvestDate.Value
AddNew.Offset(m, 7).Value = txtpH.Text
AddNew.Offset(m, 8).Value = cboNumberofCases.Value

AddNew.Offset(m, 10).Value = cboNumberofPails2gal.Text

AddNew.Offset(m, 12).Value = cboNumberofPails5gal.Text

AddNew.Offset(m, 13).Value = txtRetailPouchWeight1.Text
AddNew.Offset(m, 14).Value = txtRetailPouchWeight2.Text
AddNew.Offset(m, 15).Value = txtRetailPouchWeight3.Text
AddNew.Offset(m, 16).Value = txt2galPailsWeight1.Text
AddNew.Offset(m, 17).Value = txt2galPailsWeight2.Text
AddNew.Offset(m, 18).Value = txt2galPailsWeight3.Text
AddNew.Offset(m, 19).Value = txt5galPailsWeight1.Text
AddNew.Offset(m, 20).Value = txt5galPailsWeight2.Text
AddNew.Offset(m, 21).Value = txt5galPailsWeight3.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, or what isn't working in the second part? I got an error when not using `Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: Also, that code makes the sub write on row `A65356` + m. So really far down.

Comment: There is no bug notification, but when I click the button the new data I entered in the userform isn't entered in the spreadsheet I don't know why.

Comment: Ohh you are right. The range doesn't make any sense. But how to write set AddNew here?

Comment: Do you want it on the same row? It gets a bit weird, but try `Set AddNew = wks.Range("A1")` and then `AddNew.Offset(m-1, 6).Value` and so on (add `-1` to all rows) Or just put a `m = m-1` before you start running the addnews.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. What do you mean by in the same row? I'd like to put the information in the row m which searched first. And I tried to put m= m-1, it shows the error that "application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: I guess are you asking if I want the data I enter in the userform to be in the same row with m? Yes, the situation here is I need to enter my data in two seperated times. Here is for the second time so that I have to search by a number and find the row location first, let's say the number stands for the location of the row I want to input the new data every time,  and once I find it I need to enter the rest data and let it be put in the row corresponding to the number I just searched since I need to match the new data with the old one.

Comment: The point of doing m = m-1 is because with A1 + offset M you will always end up one row below your search, since you start at 1 and add M on top of that. Not sure you you would get an error though, without seeing the whole thing.

Comment: Oh I see. I changed my code of the problem. You can take a look at it!

Comment: Make sure m is something before using it, otherwise it'll point to Range A-1. You can put if in an if. like: `If m > 0 Then m = m -1`

Comment: That's a good one and there is no error showing up around now. But the data is somehow accidentally be put in the first row rather than the "m" row...

Comment: Make sure m is a Public variable, otherwise cmdAddRecord_Click() won't recognize the changes made to `m` by CmdSearch3_Click(). And then always run CmdSearch3_Click() first.

Comment: Yes! I forgot to paste that on here but I do have m as my public variable at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the title of your post, the question is on how to tell the userform what row you were searching. But then in the description, you are asking "should I set a click button or something else so that the data can be input in the spreadsheet? " 
I'd answer the latter with: "If you like, you can do it however you want."

As for the first part, you'd either have to pass the variable, or – which would seem easier in this case – make it a a global variable.

```
Public i as Long

Sub CmdSearch3_Click()

Dim totRows As Long, FerNum As String, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
totRows = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
FerNum = CStr(InputBox("Please enter the fermenter number you are looking for."))

If FerNum = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the fermenter number you wish to search."
Else
    For i = 2 To totRows
        If Trim(ws.Cells(i, 3)) <> Trim(FerNum) And i = totRows Then
            MsgBox ("Sorry, the fermenter number " & FerNum & " is not found.")
        ElseIf Trim(ws.Cells(i, 3)) = Trim(FerNum) Then
            MsgBox ("Please enter the data need here.")
            DTPickerActualHarvestDate.SetFocus
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

What about this to replace your top code, and then I'm guessing you make the Userform call the `cmdAddRecord_Click()` with the press of a button.

Or, you could just substitute the userform inputbox, with an ordinary one.

Declare another public

```
Public DTPickerActualHarvestDate As String
```

and then change the code where you find a match to:

```
    ElseIf Trim(ws.Cells(i, 3)) = Trim(FerNum) Then
        DTPickerActualHarvestDate = CStr(InputBox("Please enter the data need here."))
        cmdAddRecord_Click
        Exit For
    End If
```

And then in `AddNew.Offset(i, 6).Value = DTPickerActualHarvestDate.Value`, remove the `.value`

**Edit**

This is what I tried, and it seemed to work fine. Although I had to comment out the Userform stuff, since I don't have that.

```
Public m As Long
Public ws As Worksheet
Sub CmdSearch3_Click()

Dim FerNum As String, totRows As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
totRows = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
FerNum = CStr(InputBox("Please enter the fermenter number you are looking for."))

If FerNum = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the fermenter number you wish to search."
Else
    For m = 2 To totRows

        If Trim(ws.Cells(m, 3)) <> Trim(FerNum) And m = totRows Then
            MsgBox ("Sorry, the fermenter number " & FerNum & " is not found.")

        ElseIf Trim(ws.Cells(m, 3)) = Trim(FerNum) Then
            MsgBox ("Please enter the data need here.")
            DTPickerActualHarvestDate.SetFocus
            Exit For
        End If
    Next m

End If

End Sub

Sub cmdAddRecord_Click()
Dim AddNew As Range
Set AddNew = ws.Range("A1")
If m > 0 Then
    m = m - 1
    AddNew.Offset(m, 6).Value = DTPickerActualHarvestDate.Value
    AddNew.Offset(m, 7).Value = txtpH.Text
    AddNew.Offset(m, 8).Value = cboNumberofCases.Value
    AddNew.Offset(m, 10).Value = cboNumberofPails2gal.Text
    AddNew.Offset(m, 12).Value = cboNumberofPails5gal.Text
    AddNew.Offset(m, 13).Value = txtRetailPouchWeight1.Text
    AddNew.Offset(m, 14).Value = txtRetailPouchWeight2.Text
    AddNew.Offset(m, 15).Value = txtRetailPouchWeight3.Text
    AddNew.Offset(m, 16).Value = txt2galPailsWeight1.Text
    AddNew.Offset(m, 17).Value = txt2galPailsWeight2.Text
    AddNew.Offset(m, 18).Value = txt2galPailsWeight3.Text
    AddNew.Offset(m, 19).Value = txt5galPailsWeight1.Text
    AddNew.Offset(m, 20).Value = txt5galPailsWeight2.Text
    AddNew.Offset(m, 21).Value = txt5galPailsWeight3.Text
Else
    MsgBox "Variable not set"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much and it's very helpful! I just went with the first method you mentioned that put a public variable. And I changed my problem. Could you please see it again? (I don't know how to put code in the comment here sorry)

Comment: @PoppyYuan You can edit the original question. Code in comments are messy.